# Грамматическая основа БСП

Tags: бсп, основа

В общем-то парень он способный, хоть и похабник – таскает с собою ворох развратных открыток.

во 2 части - таскает ворох
а в 1??? подлежащее ОН, а сказуемое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем-то **парень он способный, хоть и похабник** – **таскает** с собою ворох развратных открыток.

1) Сказуемое: способный парень, хоть и пахабник.

**Пояснение**

Однородные сказуемые связаны уступительным союзом ХОТЬ И. Способный парень - неразложимое сочетание.

2) Второе предложение неполное, подлежащее "он" пропущено, восстанавливается по смыслу.

Answer (score 2):

Именное сказуемое "**парень**", глагол-связка "**быть**" опущен.

Comment: спасибо вам, Виктор!

Comment: @Анна : Не торопитесь помечать ответ как "лучший".  Подождите хотя бы несколько часов, другой ответ может быть более полный или даже более правильный.